# E0349 no operator ">>" matches these operands

Tags: c++

I'm new to C++, so please forgive me if this is extremely simple.

Just trying to make my own independent projects, and then this error happens to me:

> E0349 no operator ">>" matches these operands

```cpp
// usd-to-aud.cpp : This file contains the 'main' function. Program execution begins and ends there.
//
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>

// MAIN
int main()
{
    std::cout << "Welcome to Currency conversion!\n";
    Sleep(1000);
    std::cout << "This application is used to convert USD to AUD\n";
    Sleep(1000);
    int num();
    std::cout << "Enter amount in USD: ";
    std::cin  >> num();
    std::cout << num() << " is " << num() * 1.68 << " in AUD.\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You can't assign (i.e. input) a value from the user to a function, which is what `int num();` declares. May be take out the `()` (everywhere after `num`) if you just want a simple `int` variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're not intending to declare a function named `num` taking no arguments, and calling it repeatedly, simply removing the parentheses at *every* use of `num` (declaration included) should fix your problem. If it's not a callable of some sort, you don't want parens here.